# How to *correctly* open password-protected zip archives with PHP?

Tags: php, zip, crc, php-ziparchive

I was trying to open a password protected zip file with PHP but I had some troubles .. the idea was something like this ..

> Client submits password -> PHP checks whether the password is correct, if it
>   is, it returns a "correct password" message.

So, I made a zip file called *x.zip* set it's password to *1337*, and tried opening it with php using the correct password, it returned the "correct password" message, yay!, then I tried opening it with a different(wrong) password it still returned the "correct password" message :| .. here's the code I used ..

```
<?php
$zip        = new ZipArchive();
$zip_status = $zip->open('test.zip');
$pws        = [1337, 1332, 1322];  # 1337 is the correct pass!

foreach ($pws as $pw) {
    if ($zip->setPassword($pw) && $zip->extractTo(__DIR__)) {
        echo "$pw is the correct password!\n";
        /* Output:

           1337 is the correct password
           1332 is the correct password

        */
    }
}

$zip->close();
?>
```

So, I opened the .zip manually, using the wrong password which according to php is also a "correct password", and it gave me a CRC error (somehow, that's different than the wrong password error) .. How can I handle that?

Comment: Php version in use ?

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain - Tried on, 5.6.22, 5.6.3, 7.0.7 ..

Comment: Use the same code on `PHP version 7.0.8` and it is working as expected

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the PHP version .. Try doing the following, and I'm sure you'll get multiple correct password messages .. 

**(1)** Make a zip file with the password *123*  -- **(2)** Replace the foreach loop with a for loop ++ till umm, 10-20k ..

Comment: It has to do with PHP because earlier php versions had broken implementation.

Comment: Tried on `7.0.8`, and it's not working `as expected`.

Comment: Bad luck then, its working on two different servers on my end.